# Different results when using jQuery.filter and jQuery.find on Ajax xhr response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have an ajax menu on a section of my site.
This menu sends a GET request to retrieve the page content of the clicked link.
The content that I get back from the request is a full HTML page with all elements found on the page including script and style tags.
I use jQuery.filter on the XHR response to get the script as HTML script tag. 
But when I try to get style sheet link tag it is not working.
it only gives me the style link tags if I use jQuery.findon the XHR.
This is the Ajax I use

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: "html",
    async: false,
    error: function(oXHR, type, exception) {
        console.dir(exception);
    },
    success: function(xhr) {
        var scripts = $(xhr).filter('.vod'),
            styles = $(xhr).find('link[name="vod"]');
        $(styles).each(function() {
            if (this && this.href) {
                loadStyle(this);
            }
        });
        $(scripts).each(function() {
            if (this.text) {
                $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
            } else if (this.src || this.href) {
                loadScript(this);
            }
        });
        $('#container').html($(xhr).find('#content')[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Your posted link is just wrong and worst, the HTLML markup is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Jquery strips the html, head, and body tags from the response. That is because of how JavaScript works when you set the innerHTML of t adiv element. So you do not have a full html page, you have the child nodes of the body and head tags.

So you need to use filter because the link elements are not a child element.

What you are expecting : `[htmlNodeReference]`

What you get `[title, link, h1, div, etc]`

Comment: the xhr in the response is full html page as sting including THE DOCTYPE

Comment: It should not be the full HTML page... `console.log(xhr);` You should be using filter to get the link tags.

Comment: filter only gets the script tags, this is what i asked in the question, why? and find gives me the css link tag

Comment: My guess (since there is no HTMLM markup to review) is the fact the script elements are a child of another element hence why find works for them.